# How to make the Check Box checked during update in android?

Tags: android, radio-group

I am having one radio group with two radio button(self delivery and company delivery).In the application form when user select any one radio button .I am getting the text of radio button and inserting into the database by using this code .

Form.java

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                // find the radiobutton by returned id
                    radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);


                    if(radioButton.isChecked()){
                         OPTIONS=radioButton.getText().toString();
                        if(OPTIONS.equals("SelfDelivery")){
                            deliveryAddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            deliveryEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);  


                        }else{
                            deliveryAddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            deliveryEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
                        }
                    }
            }
        });
```

while the user want to edit the form i am creating new screen for edit and updating the details.by using the code .

EditForm.java

```
final String ram=extras.getString(openHelper_ob.DELIVERY_OPTIONS);// getting the option from Form.java to EditForm.java

        OPTIONS=ram;

        if(OPTIONS.equals("CompanyDelivery")){
        radioButtonCompany.setChecked(true);
            deliveryText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editAddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else if(OPTIONS.equals("SelfDelivery")){
            radioButtonSelf.setChecked(true);
            deliveryText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            editAddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }



         radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                    // find the radiobutton by returned id
                        radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);


                        if(radioButton.isChecked()){
                             OPTIONS=radioButton.getText().toString();
                            if(OPTIONS.equals("SelfDelivery")){
                                deliveryText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                editAddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);   


                            }else{
                                deliveryText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                editAddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
                            }
                        }
                }
            });
```

i want to make the radiobutton true according to the user selection while return to edit page .
For example: If user selected the company delivery ,while the user going to edit the form  in delivery option the company delivery should be checked in the edit page.

I am getting error at

radioButtonCompany.setChecked(true);

The error is

```
10-10 04:41:20.721: E/AndroidRuntime(794): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-10 04:41:20.721: E/AndroidRuntime(794): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android/com.example.android.EditBookingForm}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-10 04:41:20.721: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-10 04:41:20.721: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-10 04:41:20.721: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-10 04:41:20.721: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-10 04:41:20.721: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 04:41:20.721: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-10 04:41:20.721: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-10 04:41:20.721: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 04:41:20.721: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-10 04:41:20.721: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-10 04:41:20.721: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-10 04:41:20.721: E/AndroidRuntime(794):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 04:41:20.721: E/AndroidRuntime(794): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

With little to go on without a Logcat printout, the only assumptions that I can make are that you have not found the appropriate id within the layout for the radioButtonCompany and are getting a null pointer error.

Or, you are trying to modify the check state of the radio button outside the UI thread and therefore need to surround your setChecked within a runOnUIThread( ) { } clause.  But additional LogCat output would help significantly.